# css not pulling through

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to start a website, using bootstrap css, however, when linking to this for the Navbar it is not pulling it through.

I have tried a few different things, but unsure why this is happening as I have other sites which use the same and work fine.

Code below is from my index page

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

[and here is a screenshot of my file structure. I am sure this is something simple, but cannot work it out for the life of me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzfqJ.png)

Comment: Your path is probably wrong. Look at your own code. One CSS path starts with a slash and the other doesn't. Check your dev tools to look for errors. The code itself seems fine as you can see here https://www.bootply.com/cGwUKQDlrM

Comment: Same issue here. even if both match

Comment: Both match to what?  With slash or without?

Comment: with and without the slash is the same result

Comment: Does your custom css work ? Try to refresh the cache after making modification.

Comment: No. Neither of them are working. Tried a hard refresh and no changes.

Comment: If your index file and your css folder are both in the web folder, you should not need a slash in front of either of the css files.  Not sure what else might be affecting it.  Maybe try another browser to make sure its not holding onto the cache?

Comment: If the site is on the intenet can you give us a link to it ? If not, go in the browser tool panel and see if console or network panel give you more informations.

Comment: Site not on the internet at the moment apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tried Dev Console and the error is not showing of 404 file not found. Try using the CDN path for now: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Also you are missing the **bootstrap JS** file path too.

If it is working after this. That would mean you don't have have all the necessary bootstrap files.

Comment: With the CDN Path it works. However, I wanted the download more to be able to edit the CSS. However, guess this should be ok for now. Thanks.

Comment: Downloading it and editing it should work fine as well.  There is just something wrong with your setup that you have to figure out.

Comment: Thanks. Ill use the CDN for now. worry about the downloading and using at another point.

Comment: If it works with the CDN path. That means your setup is incorrect. I just wanted you try the CDN as it is pointing directly the file. Right click and inspect element. See if there is a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap css is a relative path. So this only works on the root of your site. The style.css has a '/' at the beginning of the path. So this works in any page as it starts from the site root. To make the bootstrap css work, add a '/' at the beginning of the path.

Comment: This is giving the same result. No formatting when looking browser.

Comment: do you have a link to the site? Does the Developer Console in your browser give you any useful hints?